# Gradle: Cannot choose between the configurations of project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
Error:Cannot choose between the following configurations of project :ViewLib:
  - debugApiElements
  - debugRuntimeElements
  - releaseApiElements
  - releaseRuntimeElements
All of them match the consumer attributes:
  - Configuration 'debugApiElements':
      - Found com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr 'debug' but wasn't required....
```

i have updated classpath ... gradle version to 3.0.1 and distribution url to 4.0..
gradle refer this link
https://drive.google.com/open?id=10ZxsarUjeXi1SqS7njCZCLKM7yaoRyZ-eIHC3IghCkI

Comment: Thanks to advance

Comment: Please post your gradle configurations code

Comment: please try above link for gradle

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing this error

Answer (score 0):

Your code probably use:

```
api project(":hiddenapis")
```

You could try replacing it by

```
api project(path: ':ViewLib', configuration: 'default')
```

This error happens because `configuration.resolve()` does not work when working on gradle project.

What I did on my gradle project is to make an extra configuration like this:

```
configurations {
    extraConfiguration // Register the new configuration
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(project(":project"))
    extraConfiguration(project(path: ":project", configuration: 'default'))
}
```

Also [Cannot choose between variants productionRuntimeClasspath and runtimeElements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66273269/cannot-choose-between-variants-productionruntimeclasspath-and-runtimeelements) suggest to use `debugRuntimeClasspath`/`releaseRuntimeClasspath` when calling `.resolve()`

I'm sorry if my answer is not perfect but I responded the best I could with the assumption I had to make, please send your `build.gradle`/`build.gradle.kts` if you want further help.