# Cannot choose between variants productionRuntimeClasspath and runtimeElements

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to upgrade [this project](https://github.com/yonadev/yona-server) from Spring Boot 2.2.4 to 2.4.3 but now I'm running into a Gradle issue:

```
Script 'C:\Users\bert\workspace\yona-server\dbinit\liquibase.gradle' line: 31

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dbinit:liquibasePathingJar'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':dbinit:runtime'.
   > Could not resolve project :core.
     Required by:
         project :dbinit
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of project :core:
          - productionRuntimeClasspath
          - runtimeElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'productionRuntimeClasspath' capability yonadev:core:0.0.8-SNAPSHOT:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability yonadev:core:0.0.8-SNAPSHOT:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.dependency.bundling 'external' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.jvm.version '11' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
```

The line 31 mentioned above is the one starting with "attributes" in the below task:

```
task liquibasePathingJar(type: Jar) {
    dependsOn configurations.liquibase
    appendix = 'pathing'
    doFirst {
        manifest {
            attributes "Class-Path": (configurations.runtime.files + configurations.liquibase.files).collect {
                it.toURL().toString().replaceFirst(/file:\/+/, '/')
            }.join(' ')
        }
    }
}
```

This occurs with Gradle 6.8.2.

My knowledge about Gradle is quite limited. I have been Googling a lot, but I cannot find out how I can influence the variant matching to address this. Your help is highly appreciated!

Regards,
Bert

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix:
If I replace `configurations.runtime.files` with `configurations.productionRuntimeClasspath.files`, it works.